# Which country produced the television series "LEXX", and where did it first air?

Tags: lexx

A bumbling security officer, and a woman transformed into a love slave escape on the dragonfly spaceship amalgam LEXX, capable of destroying worlds. They are joined by an assassin named KHI, the last of the Bruninghee race. He is sent by a cruel tyrannical ruler of the universe called the "SHADOW". Overcoming the shadow's will, he joins up with the crew of the LEXX.

Comment: This is Googled simply with just the show name, but sure, I'll look it up for you.

Comment: It was a Canada-UK-Germany co-production.

Comment: well all the input is the fun part

Answer (score 3):

## It was a Canada-UK-Germany-USA co-production.

See [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0178149/) for instance. It aired on SyFy in the US, on Space in Canada, and on Channel Five in the UK.  The main production company was maritime Canada's Salter Street Films.

**Little-known fact:** One of the main writers owned a bunch of much-beloved video rental shops in Oxfordshire, UK that closed down just over 5 years ago. (**Source:** I met him!)

Comment: Your words are bigger, so I guess you win ;)

Comment: @Mazura : Lol, if I win, it's only for narrowly beating you and Radhil to hitting the "Post" button. I say that we all win.  I'm upvoting you and Rad, since all the answers are equally worthy and correct.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The Sci Fi Channel purchased [[LEXX]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexx) from Salter Street Films, presumably first airing on the Alliance Atlantis-owned *Showcase* network.

[Salter Street Films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salter_Street_Films) was a **Canadian** television and film production company based in **Halifax, Nova Scotia**.

Answer (score 1):

*Lexx* was produced by a combination of Canadian, German, and British companies - Salter Street Films and Chum Television for the Canadians, a number of different companies depending on season for the Germans, with additional financial support from the British Channel Five.

It ran from 1997 to 2002, starting on Showtime under the name *Tales from a Parallel Universe* with it's TV-movie format first season shows, and migrating to SyFy in the US for its remaining seasons.

Comment: This was very informative, things I didn't know-I love the series, I see many sci fi influences in the show